# Big mysql innodb table - how optimize and partitioning

Tags: mysql, innodb

There is a table Mysql InnoDB:

- The table contains **22 columns**, a part of which may be **NULL**
- The first column `phone` is **required** and always contains the phone number of 10 digits (any).
- The column `phone` is **not unique** and can be more than one different strings containing the same phone
- The table is **static** and does not assume adding a row
- The size of the table near 500 million rows

How can I optimize SELECT by the `phone` on the table? Will partitioning help?

Comment: "Will it help" with *what*?

Comment: With speed of SELECT query.

Comment: And what's with it?

Comment: Is `phone` indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partitioning will be useful if your data (phone numbers) are distributed uniformly. It will be useless to have 10 partitions and 90% of your data in the first one...

First, if at all you should use partitioning, it would be ideally be a `RANGE` to avoid the overhead of the `HASH` but it has drawbacks:

Phone numbers usually contain some structure (country code, area code,...) which makes partitioning by RANGE a biased estimate.

What I would suggest if you have the possibility to, is (1) to store and index the phone numbers in **reverse** order (right to left) therefore the last digits would come first which are much more likely to be uniformly distributed.

Then, (2) if you can, I would split by as many tables as required (10 for a start) with numbers starting with the X first digits. This would thus limit the number of rows in each table to a subset of the data.

On the server configuration, store the innodb data per table, which helps indexing with concurrency.

Of course, the above only applies if you have some flexibility in your schema and if you do not need to run consolidated queries against the entire dataset.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought about the division of the table into several, using the first three digits (area code).

Comment: Now my plan:

1) Divide table into several by area code
2) Do reverse order for each
3) We done reverse for uniformly distributed for partitioning, so now i do partitioning right?

Comment: This is an idea. But I'd try without partition first to see if the performance is acceptable. Partition has drawbacks and is more prone to data corruption.

Answer (score 1):

`PARTITIONing` will *not* help; it is likely to slow down access.  Instead, have a non-unique `INDEX` on `phone`.

Better yet, *if* there is a `PRIMARY` key or other `UNIQUE` key, then change the `PRIMARY KEY` to *start* with `phone`.

If the current PK is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `id`, demote it to merely `INDEX(id)`.

There are many caveats and variations.  To discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT(s)` commonly used.